# XSD: how can I accept data that matches any of a set of types?

Tags: xml, xsd

In my schema, I would like to accept an element containing data that is formatted as either  [`date`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#date) or [`dateTime`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dateTime).

For example, any of these elements should validate:

```
<event_ts>2012-04-18</event_ts>
<event_ts>2012-04-18T12:00:00</event_ts>
<event_ts>2012-04-18T12:00:00Z</event_ts>
<event_ts>2012-04-18T12:00:00-05:00</event_ts>
```

If I just use the `dateTime` type for this element, my first example will not pass validation, as the `dateTime` spec dictates that the time of day portion must be present.

Does something like an enumeration of *types*, rather than explicit strings, exist in XML Schema?

I would really rather avoid reinventing the ISO 8601 wheel with a big regex here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a new type for your event_ts, that is defined as a union of xs:date and xs:dateTime.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xsd:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:element name="event_ts">
        <xsd:simpleType>
            <xsd:union memberTypes="xsd:date xsd:dateTime"/>
        </xsd:simpleType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

Then your XMLs are valid...